# Simple AJAX: how to swap out a div that contains a form?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Please refer to the below jsfiddle code snippet:
http://jsfiddle.net/JLXs5/3/

When the user clicks "here", I want to swap out the div that contains the signup form with the div that contains the login form (currently the login form is display:none) with a quick fade. How do I go about doing this? I'm a total novice at AJAX, and I'm having trouble making any headway in replacing the div here.

Thanks!
Ringo

Comment: The simple version is to have both forms. Make the signup visible, make the login invisible/hidden. When the button is clicked, you swap the two status so that login becomes visible and signin becomes hidden. There's `.show()` and `.hide()` in jQuery for that sort of thing.

Comment: If you go with Marc B's suggestion, there's no Asynchronous Javascript And Xml to worry about, only Dynamic HTML.

Comment: Interesting. So onclick, I will have a function that will .show the login div, .hide the signup div? How to make it fade in / fade out though? Thanks for your reply by the way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the people suggesting jQuery **JUST** to show/hide two elements...[seriously?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssRUr.gif).

**However**, since the OP wants the elements to fade in and out, and jQuery has these functions built-in ([fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) and [fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/)), it could be useful. Can also be done pretty easily with plain old JavaScript. As already mentioned, AJAX is not needed at all.

[Here is a jsfiddle that includes the fade.](http://jsfiddle.net/JLXs5/24/)